# Is 1 pixel of a height map representative of 1 vertex on the mesh?

Tags: terrain, heightmap

I'm trying to get my head around heightmap terrain generation. If I have a plane say 64 x 64 verts will I need to create a 64px by 64px greyscale heightmap in order to displace the geometry of the plane correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may be confusing some details. A height map is simply a 2D array of data. Each point represents 3 pieces of information: an `x` and `y` location and a number to represent the height at that point. For a simpler example, lets look at a 1D array of data that creates some 2D terrain. Each data point here will contain an `x` location and a number to represent the height at that point:

[image]

Pretty simple right? It's just a regular old graph. As you can see, the numbers on the x axis go up by tens. We could easily change that to go up by 100's or by .01's. Same goes for the data displayed on the y axis. We can scale those values however we like.

Basically, it's just numbers until you decide how you're going to visually represent it. So, saying a height map of 64px by 64px is already one step beyond where we need to go. Since a grayscale image is just another way to display the same data as a 3D height map. The data to represent each is coming from the same place.

[image]

Further, you don't even need a 1 to 1 relationship between data and display. You could have far more vertices than you have data points, or far fewer. They don't even need to be equally spaced.

**For the most basic example:** Yes, generate an array of `[64][64]` data points to make a grayscale image or a 3D heightmap. Each `[x][y]` of your array will correspond to the `x`, `y` of your vertices and the value stored in each `[x][y]` will represent the `z` value of your vertex.

Comment: Very clear informative answer, thank you. In effect it's just a 2D array of points being visualised.

Comment: @CaiusEugene Correct. There are multiple ways to visualize it, a simple one being gray scale images. Where the "height" value is just visualized as a color between bottom (black) and top (white).

Comment: I'm working on creating a "good looking" eroded terrain, my attempts so far are looking awful, I think I may have the wrong approach but I'm irritating through my vertices and displacing there z value based on a pixel from a greyscale image. My results are all "jagged" and don't resemble the height mapped terrains I've seen elsewhere. What could I be overlooking in this case?

Comment: That's likely a scale issue. You can try applying smoothing to the vertices after you've set them. Something like the diamond square algorithm could work.

Comment: Perfect solution by the looks of a quick google! Thanks @Byte56